# Не работает передача данных с помощью FormData

Tags: javascript, java, servlet, request, xmlhttprequest

Я пытаюсь отправить данные на сервер, используя FormData, но при запуске в отладке я даже не попадаю в сервлет, который должен обрабатывать данный запрос. При передаче данных не через FormData, а например вот так:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send( "command=addAuthor");
```

все отправляется верно, то есть проблема именно с передачей FormData. В других подобных вопросах советовали просто добавить аннотацию @MultipartConfig над сервлетом, однако это тоже не помогло. Я уже несколько дней не могу понять, в чем ошибка

js

```
async function addAuthors() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const form = document.getElementById( "authorForm" );
        const FD = new FormData(form);
        xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8081/Task1_war/main?command=addAuthor");
        xhr.send(FD);
}
```

html

```
<form id="authorForm" >
        <Label>Author (required)</Label>
        <input type="text" id="authorName" name="authorName"/>
        <label for="authorName" ></label>
        <Label>Author image></Label>
        <input type="file" id="authorImage" name="path" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg ">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" id="command" value="addAuthor" />

    </form>
```

servlet

```
@MultipartConfig
public class MainController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private void process(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        ICommand command = MainControllerHelper.getInstance().getCommand(request);
        command.execute(request, response);
    }
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        process(request, response);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.Task1.controller.MainController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Напишите сами ответ потом, чтобы вопрос открытым не висел.

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема была в том, что элемент form находился внутри другой form. И, соответственно, вложенная form не распознавалась, из-за чего я не могла получить данные формы по её id в js при отправке на сервер.